# How to pass an expression to a component as an input in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-components

I need to pass an expression to a component that will be evaluated inside an component's template.

For example, component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input items: MyClass;
  @Input expression: String;
  ...
}
```

with component's template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  {{expression}}
</div>
```

Usage of MyComponent:

```
<app-my-component [items]="listOfItems" [expression]="'[item.id] item.name'">
</app-my-component>
```

As there will be more than one input, I would like to avoid usage of TemplateRef.

Comment: What is `'[item.id] item.name'` supposed to do? That doesn't look like an expression to me. You can't pass bindings around.

Comment: pass it as `[expression]=" '{"id":[item.id],"name": item.name}' "` and use as expression.id and expression.name

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer this should evaluate to string, for item = {"id": 1, "name" : "Item1"} to [1] Item1

Comment: @AtalKishore I need input 'expression' to be generic, so in MyComponent's view I can just pass it as an expression to be evaluated or as a template, without knowing it's structure

Comment: then use `[expression]=" '[' + item.id + '] ' + item.name "`

Comment: @MarinRelatic I don't can't make sense of your comment about "should evaluat to string". Can you please elaborate a bit more (please edit the question and add it here)

Comment: I don't get what the `[` in the expression is supposed to do. Do you want to pass an array? What should the expression express?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer maybe it is not clear since I am using word 'expression'... This should be string format. So if string format '[item.id] item.name' is passed, it should write '[1] Item1'. Is there a way to make this work in Angular2?

Comment: What's the problem with Atals suggestion?

Comment: @AtalKishore I can not do it that way since variable item is undefined in parent component, it gets defined only in MyComponent's view

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Maybe one of this options can helps you:

1) Using `ngForTemplate` input property of NgFor directive:

**Component**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let item of items template: itemTemplate"></div>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() items: any;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**Parent**

```typescript
<app-my-component [items]="listOfItems">
  <ng-template let-item>[{{item.id}}] {{item.name}}</ng-template>
</app-my-component>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Li79ynezvpWuSzFDOG66?p=preview)**

2) Using the `NgTemplateOutlet` directive

**Component**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"></ng-template>
  </div>`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input() items: any;
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**Parent** remains the same:

```typescript
<app-my-component [items]="listOfItems">
  <ng-template let-item>[{{item.id}}] {{item.name}}</ng-template>
</app-my-component>
```

**[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/u2NXVTeSh6NFPPpkfNVe?p=preview)**

This way inside of `<ng-template let-item>...</ng-template>` you can use desired expression

Comment: The first one doesn't seem to work anymore. Other than the change to `ng-template` I can't figure out why its is not working for me. It gives me no items, but does error when I use the wrong `let-*` property...