# Angular2 Dynamic component display

Tags: angular

I need some advice. I'm developing a dashboard in Angular2.
My project can have different types and I want to display a component relating to each of these types.

This is how I do for now:

```
<div *ngIf="project.types.type1">
   <app-type1></app-type1>
</div>
<div *ngIf="project.types.type2">
   <app-type2></app-type2>
</div>
<div *ngIf="project.types.type3">
   <app-type3></app-type3>
</div>
```

But I would like to know if it's possible to write it in a more elegant way that could look this:

```
   <div *ngFor="let key of project.types | keys">
       <template name="app-{{key}}></template>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: you may use different Routes to load different components in the `router-outlet` based upon your project type, did you give a thought on that?

Comment: What is the content of these components (`app-type1`, `app-type2`...)? If it is just template then you can use `ngTemplateOutlet` or `ngForTemplate` like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974126/how-to-pass-an-expression-to-a-component-as-an-input-in-angular2/39977298#39977298

Comment: @MadhuRanjan my project can have many types. Each type can be display as a component, e.g.: if my project has type1, I will include the app-type1 component, and if it also has type2, I will include app-type1 AND app-type2 inside the view.

Comment: In that case you may load components dynamically using Component Factory, you will have to make a dictionary of app-type and selector though.

Comment: See also https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-content-in-angular-2-3c85023d9c36#.5x153dypu

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the looping solution you were looking for but its still a slight improvement in elegance from how you are currently doing it (in my opinion)

```
<div [ngSwitch]="project.types">

  <app-type1 [*ngSwitchCase]="project.types.type1"></app-type-1>
  <app-type2 [*ngSwitchCase]="project.types.type2"></app-type-2>
  <app-type3 [*ngSwitchCase]="project.types.type3"></app-type-3>

</div>
```