# Template with *ngIf inner, not work after change model

Tags: angular, angular2-template

**Problem**

After the version of Angular 2.2. *, I noticed a problem in some components of my application, that after updating the data, the data was wrong in the view (it presented the list with the right size, but only with the data only of the first item) .

**Demonstration**

I created [this Plunker with a simple example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XDfXknAHvybL3MSFLlPD?p=preview) of the problem.

This type of use causes the problem:

```
<list-component [data]="list">
  <template pTemplate let-item>
      <b *ngIf="item % 2 == 0">{{item}}</b>
      <del *ngIf="item % 2 != 0">{{item}}</del>
  </template>
</list-component>
```

Instructions for the problem to occur:

1. Open the example in Plunker;
2. Obverse the second block (Template with `*ngIf`:)
3. Click the "Refresh" button;
4. And look at the second block (Template with `*ngIf`:) again;

**Question**

What can be causing this problem and how to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside template with *ngIf you have several `TemplateRef`. When data is changed it is mixed.

**1)** So you have to specify which template within ng-content you are exactly using for your purpose, for example:

```
<list-component [data]="list">
  <template #tmpl let-item>  <== notice #tmpl
    <b *ngIf="item % 2 == 0">{{item}}</b>
    <del *ngIf="item % 2 != 0">{{item}}</del>
  </template>
</list-component>
```

and then in your ListComponent:

```
@ContentChild('tmpl') template: TemplateRef<any>;
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wwv0HCvzfg9zadCHBPzQ?p=preview)**

P.S. but why aren't you using `ngTemplateOutlet` or `ngForTemplate` solutions?

For Example:

- [How to pass an expression to a component as an input in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974126/how-to-pass-an-expression-to-a-component-as-an-input-in-angular2/39977298#39977298)

**2)** And i noticed in your example `PrimeTemplate` directive. So here is second option:

```
@ContentChild(PrimeTemplate) primeTmpl: PrimeTemplate;
```

and html:

```
<template-loader [data]="item" [template]="primeTmpl.template"></template-loader>
```

**[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/TCIrSmjNy32gAtojTRmF?p=preview)**