# *ngIf is not working when used inside a template tag

Tags: angular, angular2-template

We are using *ngIf inside the template tag of Angular 2, after that if we fire a click event from inside the template control then the HTML inside the template gets deleted or changes.

This is the repeater control I am using,

```ts
@Component({
selector: "repeater",
template:

`
    <div *ngIf='children'>
        <div *ngFor='let current of source'>
            <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="children._results[0]" OutletContext]="{ item: current }">
            </template>
         </div>
    </div>`
})

export class Repeater {
    @ContentChildren(TemplateRef)
    children: QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>

    @Input()
    source: Array<any>;
}
```

Here is my app-component code

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<repeater [source]="dllApprovalStatus">
          <template let-data="item">
         {{data.name}}
              <p *ngIf='data.name==1' (click)='myclick(data.name)'> Array value {{data.name}}</p>
          </template>
        <repeater>`,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
   dllApprovalStatus: any = [{ name: 1 }, { name: 1 }, { name: 0 }];
   constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

   myclick(data: any) {

   alert(data);
  }
}
```

Here I have also made a plunker repo http://plnkr.co/edit/XHZz52?p=preview.

Here if you click on the array list of the output, the template will change.
This was working fine in Angular 2 rc4 but we have upgraded to Angular2 ~2.2

Comment: Looks like a change detection bug to me. If you replace `myclick(data.name)` by `null` it still updates the view when an item is clicked. http://plnkr.co/edit/xDu0H1?p=preview (calling `cdRef.detectChanges()` didn't change anything). To get items from `children` call `this.children.toArray()` instead of accessing the private member `_result`.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/NGVRw5?p=preview See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068032/template-with-ngif-inner-not-work-after-change-model

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it worked perfectly.