# Pass scope data into ng-content in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking for solution to pass current component scope data into `ng-content` directive.

I've `app-table` component template with data I want to pass into child content, using some solution like this:

```
<!-- some html before -->
<table>
    <!-- complex header markup with sorting/filtering support -->

    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
         <ng-content [value]="item"></ng-content> //how to pass data?
    </tr>
</table>
//some html after
```

And page template where I want to use this data:

```
<app-table>
     <td>{{value.Name}}</td>
     ...
</app-table>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what about @Input?

Comment: I need `ng-content` as I have many other templates inside `app-table`, like empty table, etc

Comment: I guess you're looking for `ngForTemplate` or `NgTemplateOutlet` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974126/how-to-pass-an-expression-to-a-component-as-an-input-in-angular2/39977298#39977298

Comment: @VadimB have you found a solution to this? I am facing exactly same problem here

Comment: @yurzui, unfortunately no :( I had no time to dive deeper inspecting this problem. Also do not found any useful information regarding this feature on official documentation.

Answer (score 24):

I faced the same issue, for more clarification, I added your example working.

```
<!-- some html before -->
<table>
    <!-- complex header markup with sorting/filtering support -->

    <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
      <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{$implicit: item}"></ng-template>
    </tr>
</table>
//some html after
```

In the Component, you need to declare `templateRef` like this.

```
export class AppTableComponent {
  ...
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;

  ...
}
```

Then use your component like this.

```
<app-table>
 <ng-template let-item>
     <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
     ...
 </ng-template>
</app-table>
```

Comment: `ng-template` is one of the most confusing parts of Angular, IMO. Thanks for sharing this. It makes a great reference every time I have to look it up.

Answer (score 14):

I think you could find your answer here: [Angular 2 passing html to ng-content with bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42878506/angular-2-passing-html-to-ng-content-with-bindings).

The ng-content component is badly documented, unfortunately. It will be soon, according to the Angular GitHub issue (https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3099).

Answer (score 6):

for advance:

1. set name for template for use more than one template
2. pass more than one parameter

use this code:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmplRef;
            context: {$implicit: item, item2: item2}">
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tmplRef2;
            context: {$implicit: item, item2: item2}">
    </ng-container>
  </tr>
</table>

export class AppTableComponent {
  ...
  @ContentChild('tmpl') tmplRef: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ContentChild('tmpl2') tmplRef2: TemplateRef<any>;
  ...
}

<app-table>
  <ng-template #tmpl let-item let-item2="item2">
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td><td>{{item2.Name}}</td>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #tmpl2 let-item let-item2="item2">
    <td>{{item.Name}}</td><td>{{item2.Name}}</td>
  </ng-template>
</app-table>
```

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted, it's the best plain and simple answer I found. 
thank you very much!