# Pass html defined in parent to child

Tags: angular

I am trying to define some html in my parent component that can be passed to the child component. Is this possible? I have tried a couple of things like this: [How to pass an expression to a component as an input in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39974126/how-to-pass-an-expression-to-a-component-as-an-input-in-angular2/39977298#39977298), but I did not have any luck. Maybe my syntax was wrong. I was a little confused with the `let`.  Appreciate all the help and any explanations to help me understand this better.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-parent',
    template: `
    <div>other parent html</div>
    <app-my-child [property]="value">
        <ng-template #someTemplate">value.first</ng-template>
    </app-my-child>
    <app-my-child [property]="value">
        <ng-template #someTemplate">value.second</ng-template>
    </app-my-child>
    `
})
export class MyParent {
}
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-child',
    template: `
    <div>other child html</div>
    how do I access the template from here? Is there a way to do binding with templates? 

})
export class MyChild {
      @Input() property;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to access the exact same template in both the parent and the child? If so, just create a separate file and use templateurl instead of template.

Comment: No, I dont want the same template for both the parent and the child. There is other html, I don't want to replace the whole template.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to add an ng-content tag to your child component so angular knows it's supposed to transclude content and where to put the content:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-my-child',
    template: `
    <div>other child html</div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class MyChild {
}
```

then you need to remove the ng-template tags, because that tells angular to actually not render these things at all, because they're templates meant to be used elsewhere

Using it in the parent is super simple:

```
<app-my-child>Anything put between these component tags will be transcluded to the ng-content tag</app-my-child>
```

Comment: So how does the child `ng-content` know what element to look for in the parent. Or how are they linked?

Comment: if you only have one ng-content, anything inside the componente tags gets transcluded into that zone. so <app-my-child>All of this will appear between the ng-content tags in my child component</app-my-child>, but if you want multiple ng-content tags in the same component, then you need to use selectors to indicate which item goes where. But it seems you don't have that issue here.

Comment: What if i introduce a new component.  So lets say it is a table and a row. I want to include some row html but access it from the table template. I will create a new question and link it here. I understand the concept better with your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but what you're talking about is a much more advanced topic, pretty much reserved for building angular libraries for distribution or heavy re use across applications.  If this is your goal, I think angular university has a good course on it.

Comment: here's a link to their article about it: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

Answer (score 6):

As @bryan60 pointed out, the child template needs an `<ng-content>`. In the parent, everything you put within the child selector will be displayed at the ng-content location immediately before the [`AfterContentInit()`](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence) lifecycle hook executes:

Parent component template:

```
<child-cmp>
  <p>This will appear within ng-content of ChildComponent</p>
</child-cmp>
```

Child component template:

```
  <h2>I am ChildComponent</h2>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
```

[**Live demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpvgak?file=app%2Fchild.component.ts)

Comment: I appreciate the demo. Thanks.